# chart.js pie chart: how to disable segmentShowStroke but leave outer border intact?

Tags: javascript, chart.js2

I'm using chart.js 2.4.0 for drawing some Pie charts. I don't want the border between segments to be drawed, but I need the outer border to be. How can I obtain this?

```
segmentShowStroke: false
```

doesn't work anymore, and

```
elements: { arc: { borderWidth: 0 } }
```

removes BOTH segment and outer borders.
Thanks in advance.